# Append synthetic data to sklearn diabetes dataset

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have been using the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58905393/append-add-data-to-scikit-iris-dataset) about adding a few rows to the sklearn diabetes dataset to test the impact of extreme data values. Is there a "batch" way to append thousands of rows to the sklearn.diabetes so I can test using my synthetic dataset?

**EDIT/UPDATE**
The sklearn diabetes dataset comes with 450 rows. I generated a synthetic dataset that extends the rows to 3500. The example is below, and the entries match in format and type to the sklearn data.

[image: Data format and types.]

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, thank you but unfortunately, it also seems to be limited to appending only limited variables and a few rows at a time. My synthetic dataset has over 3K lines (also have it as a CSV).

Comment: `pd.concat()` can concatenate entire dataframes - large dataframes.  Perhaps if you showed your data formats, specific possibilities could be presented.